# ¿Cómo aumentar el ancho de las columnas en Bootstrap?

Tags: css, bootstrap, web, design

Estoy desarrollando una página web para el portfolio de un amigo, y estoy utilizando HTML, CSS y JS muy básico. La cuestión es que estoy utilizando Bootstrap para la maquetación, pero la página tiene mucho margen a la izquierda y a la derecha, y me gustaría que se acercasen mas a los laterales. Os pongo una imagen para que lo entendáis.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaría mover el logo (arriba a la izquierda) y las redes sociales (abajo a la izquierda) hasta alinearse con el texto vertical de la izquierda. Y lo mismo con el menú y el copyright hasta el texto vertical de la derecha.

En el código ya tengo nombradas las clases como "text-left" para el logo y las redes sociales, y como "text-right" para el menú y el copyright, pero eso es lo máximo a la derecha que lo puedo forzar. Quizás es porque estoy en un monitor de 27", pero quiero reducir el espacio en los laterales moviendo dichos elementos.

```
        <div class="col text-left logo">
            <img src="img/Logo-web.png" alt="Logo">
        </div>
```

Los textos verticales están colocados con márgenes y porcentajes, por lo cuál para hacerlo responsive voy a tardar.

Muchas gracias de antemano!

Comment: Con bootstrap usas la clase container, yo la sacaba y ponía la clase contenedor y creaba en el css un .contenedor { margin: 90%, height: auto } no se si algunas de las clases modifica al container o tenes que meterte al css y modificarla por eso hacia lo que te comente

Comment: Vale, voy a probar lo que comentas a ver si me funciona. Muchas gracias!

Comment: @Juan podrías indicarme porqué aplicas un margin con valor 90% al contenedor?

Comment: Viendo la propiedad `height` al lado me hace creer que en vez de `margin` se refiere a `width`.

Comment: Perdon, era width

Answer (score 0):

Por lo general en el div con la clase del contenedor es:

```
<div class="container">
  ...
</div>
```

Lo que debes agregarle es **fluid** en la clase del contenedor

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  ...
</div>
```